# Simplest quantum Monte-Carlo method for the Bose-Hubbard model

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, computational-physics, algorithms, bose-hubbard-model

I want to use quantum Monte-Carlo results to benchmark an algorithm for the Bose-Hubbard model. There are so many QMC methods in the market, so which one is the simplest one? I want the ground state energy, some simple correlation functions. I thought of using the open toolbox of ALPS, but was frustrated by the lengthy guidance.

Could anyone give me some suggestion?

Comment: How are you defining "simplest" in this case?

Comment: It could depend on the details of the system. For example, do you happen to have a fixed number of bosons, or do you want them to in principle be able to go up to infinity? and what's the interaction you have in mind?

Comment: @Gitef  I have a fixed number of particles, and I have an onsite interaction, that is, my model is the standard BHM.